# Sessions in variable vs sessions in database in golang

Tags: authentication, go, session-cookies

I am currently working on a Rest-API using Golang. That API includes authentication so I manage to save the sessions id in a map. Everything is working very well, but now am wondering if I should save the sessions id in the database. I am thinking in things like security, memory usage, performance and standars used in the industry.
So which is the best approach to make it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a RESTful API as you are, consider using authentication bearer tokens instead. You may wish to consider using [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) for that. A RESTful service wants to have as little (preferably none) server side state as possible.

As this is a Go question, a good library for using JWT and JWE is [go-jose from Square.](https://github.com/square/go-jose)

Comment: No, it just handles the creation, verification and encryption of them. What you actually do with them and how they are handled are up to you - or by another library. This fits Go's philosophy of a lot of small libraries doing one thing well.